# Difference in VBA code between mac and windows when opening them

Tags: excel, vba, windows, macos, encoding

I'm encountering a strange thing between mac and windows where it changes strings in the vba code when opened on windows (developed on mac)

I have the following function to return a format string as coded on mac:

```
Function FormatHelper(reqFormat As String) As String
    Dim format As String
    If reqFormat = "Accounting" Then
        format = "_-* #,##0.00 €_-;-* #,##0.00 €_-;_-* ""-""?? €_-;_-@_-"
    ElseIf reqFormat = "Percentage" Then
        format = "0.00%"
    Else
        format = "General"
    End If
    FormatHelper = format
End Function
```

`format` changes when openend on windows to this:

```
format = "_- *#.##0,00 Û*_*-;-* #.##0,00 Û_-;_-* "-"?? Û_-;_-@_-"
```

How can I make the VBA not change?

Edit:
The function is called like this:

```
dataSheet.Cells(currRow, 59).NumberFormat = FormattingModule.FormatHelper("Accounting")
```

Comment: Have you verified that the characters are being pulled as intended when the code loads, e.g., if you use asc(€)  and asc(Û) they don't give the same value between mac/windows?  I don't have anything to support that supposition, but from a quick look at what is being changed in your code, the euro symbol is the first i noticed was changed each time to the other symbol.

Comment: In trying to search, unicode should have the symbols represented with the same point (hence the point of unicode), but soem of the settings appear to be based on the local system.  Just to be certain, the source code wasn't designed on a computer/software in, arbitrarily,  France and used in Zimbabwe?  Try looking at http://www.rondebruin.nl/mac.htm and see if it might have any help.

Comment: No it is totally strange. I just develop on a mac machine. When my collegue who uses a windows computer opens the excel file and the vba code the format string has changed. Interestingly when he saves it and I open it on my mac again the weird symbols were also saved.

Comment: did you specify the file format when saving?  https://my.usgs.gov/confluence/display/biodata/Saving+files+in+a+Unicode+file+format+for+international+character+support goes into some details about how to ensure your save is unicode for Excel-Mac.  Beyond that, I am not sure what to offer as another suggestion.  All my other digging indicates that this is a bug between windows/mac with no (subjectively) logical fix; the only fixes I have seen listed are to export the code from mac (text file, etc.), open file from windows and import the code to see if it helps.  Sorry that wasn't more help

Comment: I'm with Cyril. You should compare the ascii codes of all chars used in the format string after entering them on both 'biotops' and see if there are differences.